# How to count how many files belong to each user/group combination?

Tags: files, scripting, users, group

How to count how many files belong to each user/group combination? I need to do this for each user/group combination that exists, in each of the directory trees /etc, /usr, and /var.

Comment: Why? Homework...?

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -printf %u:%g\\n | awk '{usergroup[$0]++}; END {for(key in usergroup) printf "%-20s %d\n",key,usergroup[key]}'
hl:hauke             401
hl:1003              10
root:root            1
```

`find` prints for every file a line of the kind `username:groupname`.

`awk` uses an associative array to count the occurrences. For every line the variable with the line content as name in incremented.

After `awk` has read the last line it prints the keys and values of the array.

Comment: This was in the LQP queue. Perhaps editing in an explanation of what that line means would help.

Answer (score 0):

> for i in /etc /usr /var; do (find $i -type f -printf "$i -> %u:%g\n" 2> /dev/null) | sort | uniq -c; done
>
> **output:**
>
> ```
>  2    /etc -> root:dip
>  1    /etc -> root:fuse
>  7    /etc -> root:lp
>  2441 /etc -> root:root
>  2    /etc -> root:shadow 
>  ...
> ```

I loop through the directories you wanted (/etc, /usr, and var).  I use the find command to find all the files in the directory, and I use the printf to display the directory and the user and group, I redirect any errors to /dev/null.  I sort the results, and then do a unique count that outputs the number and the the unique string.